# How to get X font path from Python script?

Tags: python, fonts, x11, vnc

From a Python script that is started under X, I want to get the font path.

The script passes the font path to `Xvnc` (part of TightVNC and TigerVNC). Yes, I know, to start a VNC server, one can use `startvnc`, which takes care of setting up the font path. However, `startvnc` does some things that are not desired in this case. Also, I want to use the exact same font path as on the X server that the script is started on.

I considered parsing the output of `xset q`. However:

- I don't know how reliable that is, i.e. if output is always formatted
  the same way.
- The output may contain placeholders that are not actually paths. For
  example, `built-ins` in:
  `/usr/share/fonts/misc,/usr/share/fonts/Type1,built-ins`

Comment: "I don't know how reliable that is" — it isn't, but it's the only thing you can hope to get. "The output may contain placeholders" — ignore them.

Comment: @n.m. Well, if that's the only thing I can get, I may require specification of font paths as part of the installation process. Ignoring the placeholder `build-ins` is not a good idea: Then some fonts are not found. I already tried that.

Answer (score 1):

From reading the [manual](ftp://www.x.org/pub/X11R6.8.2/doc/xorg.conf.5.html) for xorg.conf, your safest bet would be to parse the configuration file (which I'm assuming `setx q` parses) for `FontPath` lines, which look like:

> FontPath "path"
>   sets the search path for fonts. This path is a comma separated list of font path elements which the Xorg server searches for font databases.

Using python's [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module, the font paths (because multiple `FontPath`s can be specified) can be parsed like this:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'^\s*FontPath\s+(.*)\s*$', re.MULTILINE)

with open('xorg.conf') as f:
    data = f.read()
matches = regex.findall(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, my question is not specific to Xorg, so location and format of configuration for the X server may vary.

Comment: You are assuming incorrectly. There may or may not be a configuration file. `xset q` calls `XGetFontPath` (no big surprise here).

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for the corrections. I haven't messed with X11 in a while. Should've rtfm a bit more.